# How to get barcode from PDA scanner device in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode-scanner

My app installs on types of PDA devices (like datalogic, Honeywell, zkc, etc.)
I want to get the barcode scanned from these devices. So about this issue, I use RawKeyboardListener like the following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'RawKeyboardListener';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  String _chars = '';

  String? barcode;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: RawKeyboardListener(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
          if (event is RawKeyDownEvent || event is RawKeyUpEvent) {
            if (event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
              setState(() {
                barcode = _chars;
                _chars = '';
              });
            } else {
              _chars += event.data.keyLabel;
            }
          }
        },
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Barcode: $barcode',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code invokes an `onKey` callback when scanning the barcode via the PDA scanner, But the barcode (`event.data.keyLabel`) is empty on datalogic PDA scanner device.

This code works with a handheld scanner as true.
I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685366/flutter-rawkeyboardlistener-not-working-with-barcode-scanner-device) but it doesn't work for me.

How do I get barcodes from all types of PDA scanners?

Answer (score 0):

my device is AUTOID Q9 and it works.

check the normal text field when it gets focus first. To make sure your device behaves like other devices

Comment: I want to get a barcode from the PDA device without focusing on the text field...

Comment: yeah I understand your issue. I mean if your pda can get in textfield, it will work with RawKeyboardListener too.

Comment: Yeah, it works. But I want to use the PDA scanner without any interface.

Comment: Please check PDAWidget. This is my solution.

https://github.com/1712916/flutter_viblo_example/blob/master/lib/pda_page/pda_page.dart

Comment: Thanks a lot, But didn't work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It works after changing the Process mode of your scanning device:

[image]